# what is a y-axis in /joint_states/velocity[5] in rqt_plot?

Tags: ros, plot, velocity, rqt, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi . in rqt_plot  => /joint_states/position[5]

The x-axis is time in seconds and the y-axis reflects joint position in radians . but what is a y-axis in /joint_states/velocity[5] in rqt_plot ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281834/what-is-a-y-axis-in-/joint_states/velocity%5B5%5D-in-rqt_plot-?/) by [zakizadeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27970/zakizadeh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 217 on 2018-02-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From the [sensor_msgs/JointState comments](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/JointState.html):

> ```
> The state of each joint (revolute or prismatic) is defined by:
> ```

```
   * the position of the joint (rad or m),
   * the velocity of the joint (rad/s or m/s) and 
   * the effort that is applied in the joint (Nm or N).
```

So `rad/s` or `m/s`, depending on whether the joint is a revolute or linear joint.

Note that this is what the message semantics are specced to be. If a node abuses the message and puts `ticks/foot` in there, that will work, but will obviously violate semantics.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1